# error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘X509*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘EVP_PKEY* X509_get_pubkey(X509*)’

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to verify if the certificate is valid in its format, so i wrote this code but it seems that there is an error

```
if (validConfigFile()) {    
    INIReader reader(CONFIG_FILE);
    string certFile= reader.Get("Server", "cert-file", "None");
    if (certFile == "None") {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "cert-file in configuration file is not properly adjusted");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    else {
        std::string fileName(certFile);
        ifstream fin(fileName.c_str());
        if(fin.fail()) {
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "cert-file not found in its file path");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        else {
            OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
            SSL_CTX *sslctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
            SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, certFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
            SSL *ssl = SSL_new(sslctx);
            X509 *CERT = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);
            if (X509_verify(CERT,X509_get_pubkey(CERT)) == -1) {
                syslog(LOG_ERR, "cert-file not valid");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        }
    }
}
```

when compiling i get this error

```
/main.cpp:68: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(SSL_CTX*, const char*, int)’
```

and also

```
main.cpp:70: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘char’ for that line  : X509 *CERT = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);
```

Answer (score 2):

std::string has no implizit conversion to char* (C-style strings), so use the method `c_str()` instead:

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, certFile.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

Comment: what about main.cpp:70: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘char’ for that line  : X509 *CERT = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, certFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

into

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, certFile.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

Comment: what about main.cpp:70: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘char’ for that line : X509 *CERT = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);

Answer (score 1):

Try using `c_str()`

```
  SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, certFile.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
                                                ^
                                                ^
```

instead to get a `char*` from the `string`

Comment: what about main.cpp:70: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘char’ for that line : X509 *CERT = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);

Comment: So you recompiled with the c_str() fix and now you just have the line 70 compiler error?

Comment: main.cpp:70: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘char’ for that line  : X509 *CERT = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);

Comment: @AnwarMohamed OK I cant help here. You may need to create a new question as you edited your question from its original to add an additional compiler error after you already had answers. Now your question title doesnt reflect your problem